# PySimpleGUI: Using InputCombo in a second window

Tags: pysimplegui

I'm new to Python and trying PySimpleGUI. I'm trying to use InputCombo in a second, pop-up window. Here is the code, based on "Design pattern 2 - First window remains active".

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

method = 'method1'

layout = [[ sg.Text('Window 1'),],
      [sg.Input(do_not_clear=True)],
      [sg.Text('', key='_OUTPUT_')],
      [sg.Button('Launch 2'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

method_layout = [ 
    [sg.Text(' Method:', font=('current 12')), sg.InputCombo(['method1', 'method2', ' method3', ' method4', ' method5',], default_value ='method1', key='_Method_')],
    [sg.Button('Apply', key='_Apply_'), sg.Button('Close', key='_Close_')]
    ]       

 win1 = sg.Window('Window 1').Layout(layout)

 win2_active = False
 while True:
    ev1, vals1 = win1.Read(timeout=100)
    win1.FindElement('_OUTPUT_').Update(vals1[0])
    if ev1 is None or ev1 == 'Exit':
       break

    if not win2_active and ev1 == 'Launch 2':
       win2_active = True
       win2 = sg.Window('Window 2').Layout(method_layout)

    if win2_active:
       ev2, vals2 = win2.Read(timeout=100)
       if ev2 == '_Apply_':
          method = vals2['_Method_']
       elif ev2 is None or ev2 == '_Close_':
          win2_active  = False
          win2.Close()
```

When I re-open the pop-up window the second time, I expect the previously-selected value to be set. But it is not set, and the code crashes.

Comment: You cannot 're-use' a layout.  You have to make a new layout when you open the window a second time.  Closing a window destroys the widgets.  You will need to save the state yourself and set the value to the previously selected value when you create the window layout a second time.

Comment: Thank you, MikeyB. The fix was indeed simple, just moving the method_layout definition inside the "if... ev1 == 'Launch 2':" clause.

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what needed to happen. I checked the design pattern code and it looks correct, the layout was just before the call to Window.  That's a good rule of thumb.   If you're making a new window, you need to make a new layout for it.